# Why decrypting string generated in php works partially while decrypting in python?

Tags: python, php, cryptography, aes

I'm developing small app and I have issue with decrypting data in python.

First I encrypt string with AES-256-CBC in php using this code:

```
 function EncryptAES($data){
        global $KEY;
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length("aes-256-cbc");
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $KEY, NULL, $iv);
        return $ciphertext;
    }
```

Now openssl_encrypt returns base64 string(becouse I used **NULL** as 4th variable)

After that I tried to decrypt it in python but it returns only last part of string.

Here is the python code:

```
BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-s[-1]]

class AESCipher:

    def __init__( self, key ):
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ))

def Decrypt(data):
    cipher = AESCipher(KEY)
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(data).decode('UTF-8')
    return decrypted
```

Of course **KEY** variable is the same as on server.

Now after running **Decrypt()** function with encrypted data it returns only part of decrypted string.

Comment: your not padding in php but unpadding in python. guess just change to `return cipher.decrypt(enc[16:])`

Comment: Thanks for help, but I tried that. It did not help. Still returns only half of decrypted string.

Comment: if its decrypting it and its not complete garbage its working ;p I dont know python but fiddle with `enc[16:]` im sure it means something like everything after first 16 bytes

Comment: What's the intention of the `unpad` function?

Comment: If the first block of the message is garbage then you might be using different IVs.  That will munge up the first block in CBC mode, leaving the following blocks OK.  Alternatively you might have a prepended IV being treated as the first block of cyphertext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved!
For anyone wondering, you need to preappend IV in php. It is not added with default      openssl_encrypt.

Here is the code:

```
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $KEY, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$DATA = base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext);
```